# Optional can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here I define a protocol in Swift:

```
protocol DrawViewProtocol: class{
    optional func drawViewDidEndEditing() // Warning!
}
```

And Compiler gave me an error.

> Optional can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol

So what I understand is `optional` and `required` are only avaliable in Objective-C? Though, how to define a *optional* or *required* in pure Swift style ?

Comment: Pure Swift, hmm then [**Protocol Extensions**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521) may be the thing you need to check. I'm not sure if that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Swift doesn't allow protocols to have optional requirements-- if the protocol declares something, it's required. Objective-C has long had the idea of optional requirements, and Swift recognizes this when you use `@objc` when declaring the protocol. So using `@objc` is the easy way to get what you're after.

If you want a pure Swift solution, you need to add a protocol extension that includes default implementations of the methods. This doesn't make those methods optional, instead it says that any class that doesn't implement the method itself will use the default implementation instead. They're sort of optional in that classes don't have to implement them, but not really optional since that's only because a default implementation is available.

That would look something like this:

```
protocol DrawViewProtocol : class{
    func drawViewDidEndEditing()
}

extension DrawViewProtocol {
    func drawViewDidEndEditing() {}
}

class MyClass : DrawViewProtocol {

}

class MyOtherClass : DrawViewProtocol {
    func drawViewDidEndEditing() {
        print("Foo")
    }
}
```

Now if I create an instance of `MyClass` and call `drawViewDidEndEditing()`, it uses the default implementation, which does nothing. If I create an instance of `MyOtherClass`, the same method call prints "Foo".

Comment: isn't this a workaround? How do UIKit make optional function in protocols?

Comment: UIKit uses Objective-C style optional protocol requirements.

Comment: @TomHarrington Do you have solution for methods with return object?

Answer (score 22):

In **Swift 3** and **Swift 4** use **@objc** for **optional** prototype

```
@objc protocol YourProtocolName: class {
    @objc optional func yourMethodName()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the apple's documentation :  `Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to specify optional requirements.`

Please see `Optional Protocol Requirements section` from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) document.

Comment: True story Ameet. It Is indeed that simple!

Answer (score 5):

Although the above answers are *actually* right, they don't provide you with a pure-Swift answer.

The right way to do that in Swift would be to actually use protocols:

- Define your first protocol, A, with only required properties, methods, ... you name it
- Define a second protocol, B, with your so called "optional" properties
- Hence, all your classes / protocols that need to be A-compliant will be.
- Those which require "optional" compliance can be extended using compliance to protocol B.

**Example:**

```
protocol MyRequiredProtocol {
    var a: String { get }
    var b: String { get }

    func aMethod()
}

protocol MySoCalledOptionalProtocol {
    var c: String { get }

    func anotherMethod()
}


class MyFirstClass: MyRequiredProtocol {
    var a: String { return "a" }
    var b: String { return "b" }

    func aMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

class MySecondClass: MyRequiredProtocol, MySoCalledOptionalProtocol {
    var a: String { return "a" }
    var b: String { return "b" }

    var c: String { return "c" }

    func aMethod() {
        // Do something
    }

    func anotherMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a much more swifitier solution

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish it like this:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    optional func myMethod()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add @objc before protocol
this way:

```
@objc protocol FriendsTableDelegate {
    func didSelectFriend(friend: User) -> Void
    optional func didSelectFriend(friend: User, cell: FriendCell) -> Void
}
```